# Unexpected behavior of number representation on JVM in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jvm

From documentation on [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#numbers-representation-on-the-jvm)

> **Numbers representation on the JVM**
>
> On the JVM platform, numbers are stored as primitive types: `int`, `double`, and so on. Exceptions are cases when you create a nullable number reference such as `Int?` or use generics. In these cases numbers boxed in Java classes `Integer`, `Double`, and so on.
>
> Note that nullable references to the same number can be different objects:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val a: Int = 100
    val boxedA: Int? = a
    val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a

    val b: Int = 10000
    val boxedB: Int? = b
    val anotherBoxedB: Int? = b

    println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // true
    println(boxedB === anotherBoxedB) // false

    val c: Int = 101
    val boxedC: Int? = c
    val anotherBoxedC: Int? = c

    println(boxedC === anotherBoxedC) // true
}
```

Unexpected behavior: if variable c takes a value of `101` then the expression `(boxedC === anotherBoxedC)` returns `true`. What is the explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: in the JVM, Integer caches values between `[-128,127]` (and may cache other values outside of this range) so your `boxedC` and `anotherBoxedC` are the same object, hence the `===` yields true. [Integer in JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and [Discussion on this on kotlinlang](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/boxing-of-number-giving-true-for-number-less-than-128/15927)

Comment: Although this stuff is good to know about, in practice it shouldn't matter because you should never need to compare boxed primitives by reference.  In Java, it's fairly common because calling `.equals()` is a lot of hassle, especially if you have to take nulls into account — but in Kotlin, `==` is even easier than `===`!